# Reading values from property file through NANT

Tags: nant

How can I read a value alone from the property file. For example, how can I read the values of build.home or temp.dir from the below example.

contents of env.properties

```
build.home=c:\build 
temp.dir=c:\temp
```

Regards

Sarathy

Answer (score 7):

We do this in a slightly different format for Nant.

In your build file:

```
<include buildfile="./env.properties" failonerror="true"/>
```

env.properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project>
   <property name="build.home" value="c:/build"/>
   <property name="temp.dir" value="c:/temp"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. Hope it would help me. I have got one more question... Can we mark carbon copies to the mails that are sent through MailLoggers